# Indesign cant bring layer to front

Tags: adobe-indesign, layers

Hey apologize this is going to be painfully basic Indesign Help question. I am creating a "news article layout". I have a text quote, and a rectangle I want to use to "space out" so the text wraps neatly around the rectangle.

The goal of the rectangle simply is to act as a spacer. However, the rectangle is preventing the text quote from being displayed.

I've tried object --> bring to front. I've also moved the layer ontop & into a new group. I'm most familiar with photoshop and not sure what to do here.

[image: screenshot of article with the rectangle blocking the quote]

Answer (score 2):

Text wrap options don't really care about layer order (unless both have text wrap)...

You can set a specific text frame to ignore the text wrap by opening text frame's options (*Object → Text Frame Options...*) and checking "Ignore Text Wrap".

[image]

If your trying to fill the space with text it's probably better to simply use the same text frame for the text and creating the space... just set the text wrap options on the text frame:

[image]